# alternative to switch / if else statement?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a 'tarot' card reader, and I've gotten to the part where I have to add the 'predictions'.
Only issue is, I've realised there's going to be 40+ possible answers.

Instead of writing 40+ switch cases, is there a quicker way to compare two variables and output something based on that?

Thanks!

Comment: The one other way is to use a table. The table can have a range of the expected result, for example, and then the corresponding answer.

Comment: Depends on how your data is setup, you may be able to use a comparable loop. If the conditions are pretty unique, you're looking at a lot of conditional statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your data in a hierarchical structure that you can traverse based on the respective values of your two variables. That way determining the value is as simple as dereferencing the object: `options[variable1][variable2]`. See the example below.

In the snippet, the two dropdowns control the values of the two variables.

```js
var options = {
  "A": { "C": 1, "D": 2 },
  "B": { "C": 3, "D": 4 }
}

$(function() {
    $("#dd1, #dd2").change(function() {
        var opt1 = $("#dd1").val();
        var opt2 = $("#dd2").val();
        var value = options[opt1][opt2];
        $("#result").text(value);
    });
    $("#dd1").change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dd1">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
</select>
<select id="dd2">
  <option>C</option>
  <option>D</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Always amazed at how a question about basic ECMAScript prompts an answer dependent on a DOM library.

Comment: @RobG The answer has nothing to do with a DOM library. The answer is to lay out data in a JS object and reference accordingly. The DOM library is purely for the demo, because typing `document.getElementById` is more work than `$("#...")`. Even though I just did it...

Comment: `$("#dd1").val()` is simpler and faster as `this.value`, so saved you some typing there. :-) But the OP didn't even mention "DOM", apparently that part is sorted (if it's required at all).

Comment: @RobG Maybe--the question was altogether vague, so I was hoping a runnable solution might help the OP understand the solution a little better (since there's no real data to put in the object). The change handler was definitely more concise this way!

Comment: thank you nbrooks! I was able to easily understand this and modify to fit what I need.

Comment: it's nothing to do with jQuery, it's more about using selector instead of switch/statement branching.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookup table and loop through all the answers. You might want to use coffeescript or lodash to deal with loops

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what algorithm you are attempting to implement, you haven't provided it. But if you are looking up card values, then an object is one solution:

```
// cards is an array of cardNames to get the value of
function getValues(cards) {
  var values = {
    cardName0: value,
    cardName1: value,
    cardName2: value,
    ...
  }
  var result = 0; // String? Number?

  for (var i=0, iLen=cards.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    result += values[cards[i]];
  }

  return result;
}
```

Maybe the value of the result maps to some sage advice, use another object. Maybe even randomly select one of say 5 similar pieces of advice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like a lookup table:

```
var tarotLookup={
  death:"something bad going to happen!",
  hermit:"so lonely!",
  pope:"",
  moon:"spoooky!"
};
var tarotResults=["death","hermit","pope","moon"];
var predictions=tarotResults.map(function(id){
  var msg=tarotLookup[id];  
  return  [id,msg?msg:"(no entry)"].join(": "); 
});
predictions.join("\n");

//output result:
/*
death: something bad going to happen!
hermit: so lonely!
pope: (no entry)
moon: spoooky!
*/
```

You will need to make sure that none of your keys accidentally match that of property/method names in the Object prototype (which probably isn't an issue for tarot card names).  In such a case make a lookup table from `Object.create(null)` or prefix the keys to prevent such collisions.